# Бесконечно долгая загрузка glassfish4 или glassfish5

Tags: java, java-ee, glassfish

Пытаюсь запустить сервер glassfish4 или glassfish5 с помощью команды

```
asadmin start-domain domain1
```

но у меня идет бесконечная загрузка и через какое то время продолжительное время появляется сообщение о неудачном запуске, в гугле не нашел инфы по этому вопросу, мб я плохо гуглил. У меня операционная система windows 10
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Также порт 8080 становится занят и нужно ввести логин и пароль, но не знаю где их взять.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
По поводу установки, скачал zip от сюда https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download Full Platform, смотрел туториалы и прочее, везде все работает и запускается. Помогите разобраться с проблемой

jstack -F:

```
Attaching to process ID 4048, please wait...
Error attaching to process: Doesn't appear to be a HotSpot VM (could not find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypes" in remote process)
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Doesn't appear to be a HotSpot VM (could not find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypes" in remote process)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupVM(HotSpotAgent.java:411)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:305)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:140)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:185)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
```

Comment: Сними *stack trace* потока при помощи `jstack -F <PID>` и приложи его. PID можно узнать через диспетчер задач. Скорее всего у тебя какое-то приложение что-то очень долго пытается делать в синхронном режиме.

Comment: @Темкатоже Приложил к вопросу

Comment: jstack не смог присоединиться к процессу, попробуй из под администратора выполнить эту команду или просто попробуй сделать повторно.

Comment: @Темкатоже на любой pid такая ошибка

Comment: jstack из той же java используешь?

Comment: @Темкатоже да, у меня только 8 есть

Comment: @Темкатоже спасибо за подсказки, у меня на этом порту висел oracle через службы закрыл его, теперь все ок